# Include a program code with special symbols in HTML5 page?

Tags: html

I am writing an article and I need to include a program code written in C++ in an HTML5 page. I have used tags `<PRE></PRE>` but lines with `#include` statements look like

```
#include
```

instead of for example

```
#include <iostream>
```

So I need an advice how to do the task such a way that the program code would look without a distortion and formatted.

Comment: 47k and still including 'thanks' in the question?

Comment: @Scimonster  I need a one-minute answer that to do the task at once.:) I have no even time to search the internet.

Comment: So? Is that an excuse to skimp on question quality? I might say that adding 'thanks' and now discussing it takes more time than just leaving it out in the first place. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `<script type="text/html">` tag to stop it from being parsed, and then use regular JavaScript to render it on the page.

```
<script type="text/html" class="code">
#include <iostream>
</script>
<script>
var code=document.getElementsByClassName('code'),pre;
for (var i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
pre=document.createElement('pre');
pre.innerHTML = code[i].innerHTML.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
code[i].parentNode.insertBefore(pre,code[i]);
}
</script>
```

Here, i include the code inside the first script tag, and add a class `code`. Then, in the next script tag (actual JavaScript), i iterate over all the `.code` elements, do the replacement of special characters (`&<>`), and then put it in a `<pre>` tag in the place of the original code.

So, include the HTML scripts where you want them to appear in the document, and the other script at the end.

Comment: It is too complicated. I need a simple method of coping and paste

Comment: You copy/paste your code into the first `<script>` tag. You include the second script tag in your page. All done!

Answer (score 3):

If you do a simple find-and-replace before pasting it, you can escape the `<>` signs, and some others that cause trouble (`&`). Just replace `&` with `&amp;` (do this first!), `<` with `&lt;`, and `>` with `&gt;`.

Comment: I would like to do the task quickly without changing the original code that in any moment I could substitute one code for another. And I need copy the code backward and forward that it could be compiled.

Comment: Those characters are reserved in HTML, you must replace them if you want them to show.

Comment: So is no there a way to insert a text as is?

Comment: My other answer is the closest you can get - paste in your code, and another script will automatically fix up the code.